# Emit signal for GIO.DBusProxy in Python?

Tags: python, dbus

I'm using the GIO high level `DBus API -  DBusProxy` object. I'd like to emit a signal on this object (faking a signal coming from a remote interface).

I do something like this:

```
proxy.emit('g-signal', sender_name, signal, params)
```

The signal is emitted and then caught - the sender name and signal parameters are OK, however `params` is always `None` in the signal handler, no matter what I put there (I tried GLib.Variant types and also Python types). The signals received normally do have the `params` value defined.

What is the issue? How do I set `params` in the emit functions?

Comment: This is a programming question. You'll probably get better answers from a programmer community in Stack Overflow.